# django static block error on extended html

Tags: django, django-templates

Im having this error:

```
    Error during template rendering

    In template /home/ibaguio/Projects/wifination/wifination/wifination/templates/base.html, error at line 4
    Invalid block tag: 'static'
```

I have these files:

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/social-buttons.css' %}">
{% block main %}{% endblock %}
...
```

**test.html**

```
{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block main %} <div>some html code here</div> {% endblock %}
```

where obviously, test.html extends base.html, when rendering, i get the error above. But when i tried placing the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/social-buttons.css' %}">
```

lines to **test.html**(instead of **base.html**), there is no error and the page is rendered perfectly.

does anyone know the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the tag first

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/social-buttons.css' %}">
{% block main %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, loaded tags and filters are not inherited with `extend` and it's a good thing. Load what you need, only when you need it.